# Website not loading everything

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

My website isn't loading all of it's content. 
this is what it looks should like on CodePen: https://codepen.io/ArchivalBoat50/full/mWjRqK/

But this is what it actually looks like:
https://archivalboat50.github.io/marsproject/intro/

I checked the console and it says it has an HTTPS error

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alpha').addClass('in');
  },1000)
   $(".main-button").click(function(event) {
     this.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
     
   })
})
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'agency';
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62921/agency_fb-2.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62921/agency_fb-2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62921/agency_fb-2.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62921/agency_fb-2.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62921/agency_fb-2.svg#7adfd2e465e5a5494cfebbc2416928d9') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
       
  font-style:   normal;
  font-weight:  400;
}


html {
  font-size: 20px
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("http://www.newforestobservatory.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/starclusters/m56_hsiii_nfo.jpg")
}
.alpha {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-family: 'agency';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 5em;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0)scale(1.4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 4s ease-out, transform 4s ease-out, letter-spacing 4s ease-out, -webkit-filter 3s ease-out, filter 3s ease-out;
  filter: blur(20px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  &.in {
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0)scale(1);
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

red-highlight {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,3,0.3);
}

.mars {
  width: 75%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  animation: mars 30s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes mars {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0)rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0)rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.center-element {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-button {
padding: 17px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0);
border: 3px solid white;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
transition: background-color 0.5s, color .5s, transform 1s
}

.main-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  // transform: rotate(5deg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alpha ">  
<h1>
  Welcome to  <span style="background-color:red;">Mars</span>
  </h1>
 <div class="center-element"> 
<a href="https://archivalboat50.github.io/allpagesDavidsGMO/">
  <a href="https://codepen.io/ArchivalBoat50/full/gmQyZQ/" target="_blank"><button type ="button" class= "main-button">CLICK TO BEGIN AN AWESOME JOURNEY</button></a>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
  <img class="mars" src="http://now.space/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/planets/mars.png" alt="" />
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Cross Origin issues .. you're requesting files from HTTPS while your website is only HTTP, either remove "s" or use Subresource Integrity (SRI)

Comment: `http://now.space` you've mixed your loading protocols.

Answer (score 2):

if you look in the console on your actual website you'll see errors about trying to load up an insecure script over http, due to this error jquery is never pulled into you site meaning it breaks as soon as it tries to run some jquery code.

it works in codepen cause they've pulled it through from a source on the same protocol as them.

Answer (score 2):

Your errors:

1. > Mixed Content: The page at 'https://archivalboat50.github.io/marsproject/intro/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Just include your script as:

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

And let server choose a protocol. That will fix another error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

2. You have multiple errors in CSS like:

> Access to Font at 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/62921/agency_fb-2.woff' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://s.codepen.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Even you included them as HTTPS you still violate CORS policy. Your better download these fonts on your site to avoid that.

Now about warnings:
You have two:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://archivalboat50.github.io/marsproject/intro/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://now.space/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/planets/mars.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

and

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://archivalboat50.github.io/marsproject/intro/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.newforestobservatory.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/starclusters/m56_hsiii_nfo.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Although it doesn't error I would suggest putting these images on your site, because the original source of the images doesn't provide a secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should make make all your links https instead of http, chrome is really hating on mixed content. The simple solution: change http to https everywhere you can.